# add and remove element to jPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have empty jpanel. After button click should add elements to it in loop. My code:

```
 radio = new JRadioButton[answerArrayList.size()];
 for (int i = 0; i < answerArrayList.size(); i++) {
    final Answer a = answerArrayList.get(i);
    radio[i] = new JRadioButton();
    radio[i].setText(a.getAnswer());
    group.add(radio[i]);
    aPanel.add(radio[i]);
 }
 aPanel.repaint();
```

But after this action panel is still empty. How  I can add items to panel and clear all items from it?

Comment: What LayoutManager is `aPanel` using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
aPanel.revalidate();
```

before invoking `repaint()`.

Side note: Take a look at [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for changing the visibility of components at runtime

Comment: aPanel.revalidate() not helped. I think CardLayout is not good way. It should be application for testing users and after user answered a question panel should repaint with new variants. Create 60-100 layers for each question is not good in my opinion

Comment: In that case post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see where the issue exists :)

Comment: I set layout to panel and it helps.